# SQL Parameterized Query with DecryptByKey in WHERE clause (VB.Net front end)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am using VB.Net to communicate with my SQL Server back end where I just added a Symmetric Key encrypted column.

When I do queries on this table without the DecryptByKey and therefore no opening/closing of the Key, it works fine.  Once I add it to the WHERE clause it bombs although my thought is that's probably related to the opening/closing of the Key.  Here's some code to look at...

VB.Net code that calls SQL Server

```
Dim _cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim _dataset As New DataSet
Dim _dataapt As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Dim _command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

_cn.ConnectionString = "fake connection string"
_cn.Open()

_command.CommandText = _SQL

If Not _parameters Is Nothing Then
    For _x As Integer = 0 To _parameters.Count - 1
        _command.Parameters.Add(_parameters(_x)._parameter, _parameters(_x)._type).Value = _parameters(_x)._value
        // _parameter = "@unencryptedValue", _type = SQLDbType.VarChar, _value = "12345"
    Next
End If

_command.CommandTimeout = 600
_command.Connection = _cn

If _cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    _cn.Open()
End If

_dataapt.SelectCommand = _command
_dataapt.Fill(_dataset)

_dataapt.Dispose()
_command.Dispose()
_cn.Close()
_cn.Dispose()
```

SQL code being sent

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestKey 
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE TestCertificate;
GO
SELECT 1  
FROM TestTable
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(encryptedField)) = @unencryptedValue
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY TestKey;
GO
```

If it wasn't noticeable above, @unencryptedValue is a varchar(50) with a value of "12345"

I get 2 errors back, both saying System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

When I run this query directly in an SSMS query window it works fine.

I know that GO has to be on it's own line so when I create the string that goes into _SQL I put ChrW(13) & ChrW(10) before and after it each time.

Also, I know doing DecryptByKey in the WHERE is slow and probably not a good idea, but the table will stay small so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: GO is understood only by the IDE of Sql Server Management Studio. If you want to send more than one command text then separate them with a semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GO` is not part of the SQL language. It's a batch separator used by tools like Management Studio, but it's not something that's understood by Sql Server itself.

Instead, you can separate individual statements with a semi-colon (or often even with just a line break), and separate batches by sending separate calls to the database (distinct ExecuteNonQuery/ExecuteScalar/ExecuteDataReader/Fill function calls).